# Why does this override of a generic method work with 1.6, but not 1.7?

Tags: java, generics, java-7

Given the following class, which overrides the getListeners method from AbstractListModel:

```
import java.util.EventListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

public class GenericBug extends AbstractListModel {

/**
 * This is the method of interest
     * This is the exact same method signature that is present in the base class
 */
@Override
public <T extends EventListener> T[] getListeners(Class<T> listenerType) {
    // do something useful here...
    return super.getListeners(listenerType);
}

// Not important here
@Override
public int getSize() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return null;
}
}
```

This class compiles fine using an Oracle 1.6 JDK. Trying the exact same class using an Oracle 1.7 JDK, I get compile errors saying there is a name clash, but the method isn't overridden (but it is!!)

Here is the error I get when I use JDK7:

```
% /usr/java/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac GenericBug.java
GenericBug.java:10: error: name clash: <T#1>getListeners(Class<T#1>) in GenericBug and <T#2>getListeners(Class<T#2>) in AbstractListModel have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
        public <T extends EventListener> T[] getListeners(Class<T> listenerType) {
                                             ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends EventListener declared in method <T#1>getListeners(Class<T#1>)
    T#2 extends EventListener declared in method <T#2>getListeners(Class<T#2>)
GenericBug.java:12: error: incompatible types
                return super.getListeners(listenerType);
                                         ^
  required: T[]
  found:    EventListener[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends EventListener declared in method <T>getListeners(Class<T>)
GenericBug.java:9: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
Note: GenericBug.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening? Is this a compiler bug in JDK1.7, or am I missing something?

Comment: Include the declaration of getListeners() from AbstractListModel.

Comment: The error message says that the GenericBug.getListeners() method signature does not match the AbstractListModel.getListeners() signature (i.e. does not actually override it), so it is complaining about the @Override annotation.

Comment: @DwB `public <T extends EventListener> T[] getListeners(Class<T> listenerType)`

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but why not remove the override from GenericBug, since it is just proxying the call to the super?

Comment: @DwB Removing the override annotation doesn't help. I get 2 compile errors instead of 3. With respect to the overridden method not doing anything useful, I realize that. I'm just trying to make my example as simple as possible. I really am doing stuff in this method, but I'm not showing it here, because it is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: The reason the @override is flagged as an error is because java 1.7 sees the T of the super class as different from the T of the derived class.  :( Beyond that, I'm mostly useless.  Have you tried moving the generic to the class level (AbstractListModel<T extends blah> and GenericBug<classname>)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, `AbstractListModel` is generic, you should not inherit it raw. If

```
class GenericBug extends AbstractListModel<Something>
```

the code compiles.

Now it is inherited raw, so what's happening? A raw type's instance methods all undergo erasure too [4.8], so the raw `AbstractListModel` has a method

```
public EventListener[] getListeners(Class listenerType)
```

The `GenericBug.getListeners` method in the subclass does not override this method[8.4.8.1].

This is based on JLS3, which Javac 6 should follow. So it must have been a Javac6 bug.

It appears that javac 7 has rewritten the type system algorithms, with a much better result.

JSL3: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html

Comment: Ah, that was it! AbstractListModel was NOT generic in 1.6, but it was genericized in 1.7. So it was not a bug in either compiler version, but rather the underlying class was changed.

Comment: in that case, java7 breaks backward compatibility, it's a bug in API evolution.

Comment: Let me see if I understand it. The same has happened to me with a class `ClassA` that implemented `Comparable<ClassA>`. So, `toString()` must be annotated because there is a method in `Object` that takes no arguments and returns a String, but `compareTo(ClassA obj)` has no annotation because `Comparable` only defines a method `compareTo(<T>)`?